# Query changes in specific document ids in CouchDb

Tags: couchdb

I have a mobile app that stores data (fetched from a remote CouchDb instance) to a local SQLite database. Sometimes a sync request occurs, and I would like to know of all items in the local database whether their counterparts have changed on the server. (So, whether their revision is newer than the one in the local database.)

But how can I request only the specific items in the local database, without making hundreds of separate requests, and without fetching *all* the documents in the huge remote database?

The way I currently do it, is: for each local document, first get the HTTP header, and download the body only if the header shows a newer revision than the local doc has. I worry that for users that store a lot of items locally, this will result in a lot of HTTP request

Comment: One method used by a few tools is to use checksums to trigger a sync

Comment: @Zarazthuztra could you expand on that? Checkum of what?

Comment: A checksum of anything that represents the current state of your data. Run it through MD5 or SHA-1 and then store that value in your SQLLite database. When the initial handshake is made between client and server you exchange checksums. If they're different then you know you need to sync. This is how IBM Worklight knows whether or not to update the local app, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using the [Change Notification API](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/notifications.html#polling)?
Your app could request all recent changes, and then check if any of the local files has changed on the server.
Adding a filter might help getting only interesting changes.

Comment: Nice! Exactly what I was looking for. Happy Christmas. :)